# Simple confirmation email from google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a simple(later to be put into HTML) response email when someone fills out a form. I can't work out why it's not working, so far I have:

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
 {
 var values = e.response;
 var name = values[2];
 var email = values[1];
 var items = values[3];
 var message = "Hello " + name + ", \n" +
 "This is a confirmation message to let you know we received your form submission and 
 are working on the request.\n" +
 "Name again: " + name + "\n" +
 "items: " + items ;

 var recipient = email ;
 var subject = "Confirmation Messagesdfdf";
 GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the email is gathered and the name and items is incorrect.

First you have to create an installable trigger as mentioned on [Google Forms events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) or create a manual trigger in the project.

Aside from that, the `e.response` does not provide an array but provides a [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response). There you have the different methods you can use to get the details for the answer.

A simple modification from your script to be able to send the email without the answers and the name would be:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var message = "Hello , \n" +  "This is a confirmation message to let you know we received your form submission and are working on the request.\n"

 var recipient = e.response.getRespondentEmail() ;
 var subject = "Confirmation Messages";
 GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kessy, I worked that out but I will need this information in the future to change invoice and email information with if statements

Comment: For the responses you can get them by using the method on the `FormResponse` documentation [getItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getitemresponses). For the user name you can ask it in the form and then gather it as a response to insert to the email